# Notation for unordered product of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Frequently, when referring to the edges of an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, I want to write that $E \subset V \times V$, which isn't correct since the Cartesian product is ordered and the edges are not.

This motivates my question: is there a common notation for a product of sets $A$ and $B$ defined by $\{ \{a,b\} ~|~ a \in A ,~ b \in B \}$?

Comment: $[X]^2$ is used to refer to the set of unordered pairs from a set $X$ (and $[X]^n$ for $n$-tuples).

Comment: Per the modified Question, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then the distinction between ordered and unordered pairs is without essential substance.  Given an unordered pair, $\{a,b\}$ we can identify the corresponding ordered pair $(a,b)$ by virtue of $A\cap B = \emptyset$.

Comment: @hardmath what part of my question implies disjointness?

Comment: I'm not trying to put words in your mouth; you do not imply disjointness.  I'm merely pointing out a reason that one often avoids the "messiness" of saying $C = \{ \{a,b\} \mid a \in A, b \in B \}$.

Comment: (Sorry posted my answer first here as a comment...) Please delete this ...

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112935/notation-for-all-subsets-of-size-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use $E \subseteq \binom{V}{2}$. Although, I have seen it used elsewhere, it's probably not a standard notation.

Comment: This notation is often used in graph theory.

Comment: This strikes me as awkward in general though because binomial coefficients generally mean "without replacement"

Comment: @SheridanGrant $\binom{V}{2} = \{X \subseteq V : |X| = 2\}$. Is this not without replacement?

Comment: @user76284 no recollection of this comment but I appear to be a doofus, you're right

Answer (score 2):

We used $\bar{\times}$ (but without the gap between the bar and the times symbol) in the algebraic graph theory lectures I've attended some years ago. I liked it, however I don't know how common it is.

Comment: FYI, it's not common at all (at least I've never seen it anywhere). Maybe in some fields, but certainly not in all of mathematics.